# How to convert JSON string with double quotation backslash to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object, backslash

I get response json string from server like this:

```
$scope.text = '{"response":"{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"age\":454 }"}';
```

How to use `$scope.text` in angular template page like this:

```
{{text.response.age}}
```

This is my demo [Demo](http://codepen.io/essvision/pen/PzjGpQ?editors=1011)

Comment: Read about `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $scope.text = '{"response":"{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"age\":454 }"}';
> ```

The problem here is that this isn't JSON.

By itself:

```
{"response":"{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"age\":454 }"}
```

… is JSON.

However, once you wrap it in a JavaScript string literal, the `\` is used as an escape character for the JavaScript string literal and gets consumed before it can appear in the JSON.

When you generate JSON embedded in JS, you need to escape the characters with special meaning in JS:

```
$scope.text = '{"response":"{\\"firstName\\":\\"John\\",\\"age\\":454 }\"}';
```

It would also be a good idea to redesign your data structure so that your JSON doesn't contain strings of JSON in the first place:

```
$scope.text = '{"response": {"firstName":"John","age":454}}';
```

Comment: Thanks, But how to convert it to javascript object. I added a demo page. What should I do?

Comment: @Ehsan — You need to fix the input (to make it JSON) as I described and gave an example of. The you can apply JSON.parse to it.

Comment: I can't change response that get from server

Comment: Then you'll need to look at trying to fix the errors in it, programmatically, before parsing it. Good luck.